# Workaround for executing dynamic sql in function

Tags: sql-server, function, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to create a view which dynamically generates text from input parameters. But executing dynamic sql or stored procedure is not allowed in functions. Is there a work around for this?

I'm working on SQL Server 2014
Windows 10

Below is sample script for:

1. Create tables

   - Emp_info holds the details of the employee.
   - Table_list holds the details of the tables with column table_template_id.
   - table_template_id holds the format of the data to be displayed in the view. This can be customized.
2. Create function

   - Accepts 2 input parameters (table_key and emp_key to get the formatted table_template_id)
3. Create view
4. Expected output

```
----------------1. TABLES-------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.emp_info', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.emp_info;
CREATE TABLE emp_info (emp_key INT, table_key INT, emp_fname NVARCHAR(100), emp_lname NVARCHAR(100), city_name NVARCHAR(100), city_zip BIGINT)
INSERT INTO emp_info (emp_key, table_key, emp_fname, emp_lname, city_name, city_zip) VALUES (1, 3, 'Brad', 'Pitt', 'San Jose', 95670)
INSERT INTO emp_info (emp_key, table_key, emp_fname, emp_lname, city_name, city_zip) VALUES (2, 3, 'Will', 'Smith', 'Kansas', 65870)

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.table_list', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.table_list;
CREATE TABLE table_list (table_key int, table_name NVARCHAR(100), table_template_id NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO table_list (table_key, table_name, table_template_id) VALUES (3, 'emp_info', '[emp_lname],[emp_fname]-[empkey]')
----------------TABLES-------------------------
```

```
----------------2. FUNCTION-------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID(N'crt_emp_temp_id', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION crt_emp_temp_id
GO
CREATE FUNCTION crt_emp_temp_id (@table_key INT, @emp_key INT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(1000)
AS
 BEGIN

DECLARE @mi_table_id_tmp TABLE (
table_key BIGINT,
table_fld NVARCHAR(100),
fld_order BIGINT
)

DECLARE @table_template_id NVARCHAR(100), @table_fld NVARCHAR(100), @table_flds NVARCHAR(100),
@count INT = 0, @max_fld_order INT, @table_name NVARCHAR(100),
@fld_order INT, @sql_stmt NVARCHAR(MAX), @out_value NVARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @table_template_id = table_template_id
     ,@table_name = table_name
FROM table_list
WHERE table_key = @table_key

SET @table_flds = @table_template_id

WHILE (LEN(@table_flds) > 0)
BEGIN
 SET @table_fld = SUBSTRING(@table_flds, CHARINDEX('[', @table_flds)+1, CHARINDEX(']', @table_flds)-2)
 SET @table_flds = SUBSTRING(@table_flds, CHARINDEX(@table_fld, @table_flds)+LEN(@table_fld)+1, LEN(@table_flds));
 SET @table_flds = SUBSTRING(@table_flds, CHARINDEX('[', @table_flds ), LEN(@table_flds))

 SET @count = @count + 1;
 INSERT INTO @mi_table_id_tmp (table_key, table_fld, fld_order) VALUES (@table_key, @table_fld, @count);  
END

SELECT @max_fld_order = MAX(fld_order) FROM @mi_table_id_tmp

SET @count = 1

WHILE (@count <= @max_fld_order)
BEGIN
    SELECT top(1) @table_fld = table_fld
    FROM @mi_table_id_tmp
    WHERE fld_order = @count

    IF (@count = 1)
        SET @table_template_id = REPLACE(@table_template_id, '['+@table_fld+']', @table_fld+'+''')
    ELSE IF (@count = @max_fld_order)
        SET @table_template_id = REPLACE(@table_template_id, '['+@table_fld+']', '''+'+@table_fld);
    ELSE
        SET @table_template_id = REPLACE(@table_template_id, '['+@table_fld+']', '''+'+@table_fld+'+''');

    SET @count = @count + 1
END

SET @sql_stmt = 'select @out = '+@table_template_id+' from '+@table_name+' where emp_key = @e_k'

------------This is where I'm stuck-------------------
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_stmt, N'@e_k int,@out NVARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT', @e_k = @emp_key, @out = @out_value OUTPUT
RETURN @out_value
------------This is where I'm stuck-------------------
 END
GO
----------------FUNCTION-------------------------
```

```
----------------3. VIEW-------------------------
IF object_id(N'emp_info_vw', N'V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION emp_info_vw
GO
CREATE VIEW emp_info_vw AS
SELECT crt_emp_temp_id (table_key, emp_key) emp_id,
city_name,
city_zip
FROM emp_info
GO
----------------VIEW-------------------------
```

```
--------------4. Expected Output----------------
/*
I'd like to have my output of the view as below
Pitt,Brad-1   San Jose  95670
Smith,Will-2  Kansas    65870
*/
--------------Expected Output----------------
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to create a view which dynamically generates text from input parameters."* This statement alone makes it sound like a big [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). A `VIEW` doesn't support parameters, it's a virtual table represented by a **pre-written** `SELECT` statement. A `VIEW` can only consist of a `SELECT` it's therefore also impossible for it to contain dynamic SQL, as you can't `EXEC` in one. The only place you could do this would be inside a Store Procedure. A function, also, cannot use `sys.sp_executesql`, as they cannot perform DML/DDL functions (which the statement might).

Comment: In short, to answer your question *"But executing dynamic sql or stored procedure is not allowed in functions. Is there a work around for this?"* No. If you need Dynamic SQL you **cannot** use a `VIEW` or `FUNCTION`; you need to use a stored procedure.

Comment: This entire exercise sounds like it is in the wrong layer in your application. You are doing presentation layer work in the data layer. All the code you have here is about taking the data from a table and formatting it a certain way. This should not be done by the database but by the application that is consuming this data.

Comment: *Side Note: SQL Like `'['+@table_fld+']'` does **not** make your code safe from injection. Just like a query with `'WHERE MyColumn = ''' + @MyVariable + ''';';` can be escaped with a single `'` (`1'; CREATE TABLE dbo.YouGotInjected (ID int);--`) so too can brackets (`MyTable];  CREATE TABLE dbo.YouGotInjected (ID int);--`). If you want to make an injected value secure, then use [`QUOTENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).*